# created usb boot drive using wrong drive

Tags: partitioning

need help!  i tried to create a usb boot drive.  i was successful using poweriso on one drive, then i created another one.

the second one was a mistake because i pointed to a wrong usb drive which is actually an external hard disk that has some important files in it.

how can i undo what i just did? or can i revert back or recover the old partition?

tries easeus without luck. im trying mini tool next but the lost partition has not been found yet.

any other advise?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when you selected the hard drive as the boot disk, it formatted the hard drive, wiping what was on it. Unless you have a backup of the drive, you cannot recover what was on it. The partition was overridden with the format.

Answer (score 0):

Your files may be recovered if they were not overwritten with the new data.

Here is a list of data recovery products with reviews (read also the comments) :
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Recovery is not always perfect : Some files are fully recovered,
others may be missing some pieces, and some may have their names lost and 
replaced by numbers and need to be identified.

Try these products one after the other, because not all use the same recovery methods.
If none of them can recover your data, then it seems like it is lost.